# django import-export adding an emailValidator adds a new field on export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have these models:

```
Investment
Profile
```

wherein `Investment` has a foreign key to `Profile` through email. I'm trying to bulk export but the export adds a duplicate `profile__email` without any values.

Sample result:

[image]

I noticed its from the added validator in my `InvestmentResource`:

```
class InvestmentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class ValidatingEmailForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget):
        def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                validate_email(value)
            except ValidationError as e:
                # a quirk of import-export means that the ValidationError 
                # should be re-raised
                raise ValueError(f"invalid email {e}")
        
            try:
                val = super().clean(value)

                return value
            except self.model.DoesNotExist:
                raise ValueError(f"{self.model.__name__} with value={value} does not exist")

    email = fields.Field(attribute='profile__email', 
        widget=ValidatingEmailForeignKeyWidget(Profile, field='email'), 
        column_name='profile__email')


    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        clean_model_instances = True
        import_id_fields = ('id',)
        fields = (
            'id',
            'notes',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'email',)
    
    export_order = fields

    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        self.profile__email = row["profile__email"]
        self.profile__firstname = row["firstname"]
        self.profile__lastname = row["lastname"]

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Create any missing Profile entries prior to importing rows.
        """
        try:
            # print(self.isEmailValid(self.email), file=sys.stderr)
            
            profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(email=self.profile__email)

            profile.firstname = self.profile__firstname
            profile.lastname = self.profile__lastname
            profile.save()

            instance.profile = profile

        except Exception as e:
            print(e, file=sys.stderr)
```

If I try to remove the validator and change `email` in fields to `profile__email`, the fields exported are what is expected, but when importing, the emails don't get validated. I need to be able to export the necessary fields while still being able to validate them on import. Does anyone know if I'm missing something important? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is happening because you are defining an attribute called `profile__email`:

```py
def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        self.profile__email = row["profile__email"]
```

You shouldn't need to do this because `import-export` should detect that this is a field to import if it is listed in the csv. I think if you can remove this line it should work.

However, if you want more control over which fields appear in the export, you can override `get_export_order()` to return an iterable containing just the fields you need, for example, this will export only the 'id' field.

```py
class InvestmentResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def get_export_order(self):
        return (
            'id',
            'notes',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'email'
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        # ...
```

More information in [this thread](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1294).